How much noise is perfect for that "camera" look(compositor)?
I made this scene in blender and made some compositing improvements:

I experimented with a noise texture/image in the compositing tab for that "camera" look(hope you relate with me, but I know some pictures have noise in them and it kinda looks better). Aaaand I want to know about your opinion and if it's too much/too visible or maybe too low or too big.

Your question is more about creative choices. Your render simulates a kind of mix between noise and grain, which I would recommend against. Go for a film look if you enjoy it, but avoid implementing noise. This should always be minimal in my opinion.

THello, 2sa2 this is not the kind of question we can answer in the Stack Exchange format ..  we can't rank answers that are a matter of opinion. Even if you were to ask this question in somewhere that can accommodate it, like https://blenderartists.org/, as a design problem, you would have to include a design brief, explaining the intent of the image, and constraints, such as publication format. If it's not a design problem, but purely aesthetic.. well.. that would be down to you :)

Digital noise and film grain are two distinct things. Here is a comparison (a quick simulation I did, so not 100% accurate) :

Digital noise

Reason : individual red, green or blue sensor firing for external reasons
Typical pattern size : pixel-size, each pixel independant of neighbours
Colors : fully saturated RGB colors
Most visible : in darker areas
Usually unwanted and reduced to 0

Film grain

Reason : non-uniform distribution of chemical substances on film
Typical pattern size : can be bigger than pixel-size, depends on width of film and other parameters
Colors : mostly affects luminosity (no colors), may sometimes create colors too (I'm not sure)
Most visible : in brighter areas
Depending on creative vision and personnal taste, can be wanted or unwanted

Your noise
Your noise is a mix of both.


Typical pattern size : 5-pixel circles + pixel-size ? Your render being jpg and not png, it may be a compression artifact
Colors : midly saturated colors
Most visible : in mid-gray areas ?

Looked from afar, your noise gives me a digital noise vibe which I don't like much. But I'll follow your question with great interest, as I have only a superficial understanding of this topic.

Hey, thanks for the answer. I actually like digital noise more than film grain. I would use film grain in vhs scenes with low resolution but not for any scene, as it is kinda blurry and removes some details. That's why I would continue using both noises in different scenes
